# How should I merge hash while using 'first_or_create'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this hash, which is built dynamically:

```
additional_values = {"grouping_id"=>1}
```

I want to merge it with this record object after creation via [first_or_create](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create):

```
result = model.where(name: 'test').first_or_create do |record|
  # I'm trying to merge any record attributes that exist in my hash:
  record.attributes.merge(additional_values)
  # This works, but it sucks:
  # record.grouping_id = data['grouping_id'] if model.name == 'Grouping'
end
#Not working:
#result.attributes>>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"Test", "grouping_id"=>nil}
```

I understand that if the record already exists (returned via 'first'), it won't be updated...although that would be a nice option and any recommendations on that are welcome, but the table was just dropped and recreated, so that's not the issue.

What am I missing?

I also tried using `to_sym`, resulting with:

```
additional_values = {:grouping_id=>1}
```

...just in case there was some weirdness I didn't know about...didn't make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) returns a new hash and then you aren't doing anything with that hash, you're just throwing it away. I would also suggest sticking to using the ActiveRecord methods for updating attributes, instead of trying to manipulate the underlying hash, such as using [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) or, if you want to save the record [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update). Though, you may find the [`create_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-create_with), which can be used with [`find_or_create_by`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by), useful here:

```
model.create_with(additional_values).find_or_create_by(name: 'test')
```

I can't find any documentation that I like (if at all) for `first_or_create` in recent rails versions, but if you like that more than `find_or_create_by`, then if we look at the [Rails 3 documentation for `first_or_create`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create), you should be able to do with out the `create_with`:

```
model.where(name: 'test').first_or_create(additional_attributes)
```